# How to make :hover's work on mobile while you drag your finger across the mobile screen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

I have simple html

```
<head>
<style>
  div.hdiv {width: 200px; height:200px; margin:5px; display:inline-block;}
  div.hdiv {background: red;}
  div.hdiv:hover {background: green;}
</style>
</head>
<!-- -------------------- -->
<body>
<div class="hdiv">content</div>
<div class="hdiv">content</div>
</body>
```

I would like the :hover effects to work on mobile when I drag my finger across the screen over the elements. At the moment, they only work when you tap the screen.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at touch events?

Comment: i think you cant with only css, maybe touch events with js? :) document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {});

Comment: Laaouatni Anas, as far as I know touchstart listener used to simulate hover without doing click on the element. I need :hover (or its equivalent) to work right under the finger moving across the screen.

Comment: @anthony3d ok :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a touchstart listener to the elements and add a class.

Then on toucend you can remove the class.

Note that this is all this snippet adds to the original code (and :hover will still work on a hoverable device). If you want the color to change back when the finger/stylus leaves the element then more code will be needed to sense the touch move position and if it's outside the element remove the class.

It depends on how large your 'hoverable' elements are as to whether it's sensible to do this or not given touch is less accurate than a mouse/cursor.

```js
const hdivs = document.querySelectorAll('.hdiv');

function touchStart(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.target.classList.add('hover');
}

function touchEnd(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  ev.target.classList.remove('hover');
}
hdivs.forEach(hdiv => {
  hdiv.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);
  hdiv.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd, false);
});
```

```css
div.hdiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.hdiv {
  background: red;
}

div.hdiv:hover,
div.hdiv.hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="hdiv">content</div>
  <div class="hdiv">content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What I want doesn't work that way. :(

Comment: Hi, could you describe what is not working?